# C++ error: use of undeclared identifier for global variables and array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

I am currently trying to create a list that will initialize 100 item objects but for some reason my global variables and arrays are not being recognized by the compiler. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Also if you see anything that I am doing wrong, criticism is highly appreciated.

Header for my List:

```
#ifndef List_hpp
#define List_hpp

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Item.hpp"

using namespace std;

class List
{
    private:
    static int itemcount;
    Item items[100];

    public :
    List(){
        this->itemcount = 0;
    };
    void addItem(string, string, int, double);
    void removeItem(string);
    void display();
}; //End List Class

#endif /* List_hpp */
```

CPP file:

```
#include "List.hpp"

//This method will add a new item
void addItem(string name, string unit, int quantity, double price){
    Item newItem(name, unit, quantity, price);
    itemcount++;
}

void removeItem(string name){
}

void display(){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CPP File of the class List you must put the class name before every function implementation like:

```
void List::addItem...
void List::removeItem... 
void List::display..
```

I think the implementation of addItem is not completed yet. You didn't put the new created item in the list.
You must declare a copy constructor for the class Item or use dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add those. Programming in Java and then learning C++ has a learning curve